# How do you avoid 'al tiftah peh l'satan'?

Tags: death, how-to, superstition, satan

There is a principle of [al tiftach peh l'satan](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%9F) ([Ketubot 8b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=8b&format=pdf)) - literally "don't open your mouth to the Satan". How can concern for this principle be avoided when discussing possible bad future situations, such as for instance in estate planning, where discussing one's own demise is inevitable?

Comment: The Gemara is very big on its use of euphemisms, I seem to recall an example in berachot where they say "the downfall of the haters of Israel" to refer to the downfall of the object of the haters, but don't wish to mention such a calamity.

Comment: @andrewmh20 There are many examples of this expression in the Talmud (and other writings of Chazal), for a few examples: *B'rachos* 7a (regarding the Jews who were saved from Bil'am's curses), Yoma 75b (regarding the Jews in the desert who ate the quail), M'gilla 12a (regarding the Jews in the time of the Purim story), and *Mo'ed Kattan* 9a (regarding the Jews who rightfully ate on Yom Kippur in the time of Sh'lomo). There's a similar example on *B'rachos* 63b about Torah scholars who study in isolation (if you're looking for examples from *B'rachos*).

Comment: @andrewmh20 I'm asking specifically in situations where that is not possible (I don't think euphemisms would hold water in a legal discussion of estate planning)

Comment: @Fred This technique is even in Tanach-- Shmuel Bet 12:14 (according to some Mefarshim).

Comment: Why can you not speak in 3rd person